# Eevee : Render Layer Emit pass rendering black

Tags: render-layers, emission

my emit(emission) render layer outputs black even though I have objects with materials on them that use emission surface. I can see the emission working in the Image output, but nothing in the emit pass. Am I doing this right?

[image: emission layer]

Answer (score 1):

Your emission shader blend mode needs to be set to anything other than "alpha blend". This same issue was driving me nuts cause I was trying to make faded light beams but, it just renders black.